# Error installing vcremote on Mac OS X 10.13

Tags: xamarin, installation, remote-debugging, osx-elcapitan

I'm using macOS High Sierra Version 10.13, Xcode 9.0.1, Command Line Tools 9.0, npm 5.5.1, node v8.3.0,  UnZip 6.00, ios-deploy 1.9.2. On my windows system I have MS Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin/Mobile Development Paket installed.

I'm trying to install vcremote-lib v2.3.2 and vcremote v1.0.10 on my updated mac to have a chance for finally compiling a C++ lib with an iOS app.

I tried https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77545f82-6f66-47d6-b00c-02d73089cb00/installing-vcremote?forum=vcgeneral with different version numbers of course but it's anyways not possible to compile vcremote-lib and vcremote succesfully together. I manually updated node/unzip/ios-deploy and so on (like on older posts with similar problems recommended).

Executed command:
1. sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root vcremote-lib

when okay:
2. sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root vcremote

I always get the following error:

```
Ld build/Release/ios-deploy normal x86_64 code ELIFCYCLE errno 65

ios-deploy@1.9.0 preinstall: './src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild'

Exit status 65

Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.0 preinstall script.
```

I got an additional exception info for both executed commands:

```
ld: framework not found MobileDevice

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Does anybody know how to get the vcremote-lib&vcremote to build successfully? And of course where to get the MobileDevice framework from or how to make the private framework accessible for other applications?

I tried recently to export the private framework 'MobileDevice' with the following command but again this won't affect the result from the vcremote-lib install.

```
nm /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
```

By the way downgrading to 'node 6.5' (like mentioned in [Error installing vcremote on Mac OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507679/error-installing-vcremote-on-mac-os-x-10-11)) doesn't help either.

I'm wondering if I'm the first one with this problem? Because I didn't saw a topic with newer version numbers..

Answer (score 0):

The correct contact for this issue is "Visual C++ MDD Admin Group (external)" -->

Final, helpful answer from microsoft: Steven, I’ve pushed out a new versions 1.0.12 of vcremote that should resolve this issue. Please give it a try and loop back with me if it’s still not running / installing for you. Thanks, Ian